# Flyway and JPA integration

Tags: java, spring, flyway

My current Spring 3.0 project is integrating with Flyway.

Thanks to the google site so there are document I can counting on. But unfortunately there is not much talking about integration with `JPA`.

So the questions is:

1. How to integrate Flyway with `persistence.xml`? And how does it work? Each time JPA provider will `auto generate` schema update so how we run a script before or after then?
2. I guess the query by flyway so far does not support HQL and such so is there any sample code then I can go through to know how to integrate the migration event? Design an interceptor or a new aspect?What to do on a domain level?

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flyway has no support for JPA <del>and Spring</del>. It basically runs your SQL (not HQL) scripts in order and keeps track of them. And does it well. It remains agnostic to how you use your database and how you produce your upgrade scripts.

However, there's hope. Your persistence provider will most likely support updating existing schema (I know [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) and [eclipselink](/questions/tagged/eclipselink) can), running ALTER and CREATE statements on startup. The migration SQL scripts aren't perfect and it won't always work, but it's a good start. Log these scripts, collect into SQL file, clean-up and use as `V_*.sql` file supplied to Flyway.

UPDATE: although there is no direct support for [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) framework, you can easily [integrate it with existing Spring application](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api.html). This approach is proven to work on production and plays nicely:

```
<bean id="flyway" class="com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="..."/>
  ...
</bean>
```

Bonus: it works great with Java configuration (with Scala) as well:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
def flyway() = {
    val fly = new Flyway()
    fly.setDataSource(dataSource)
    fly
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see much about JPA supporting from Flyway, but it even doesn't support Spring? That really disappoints clients from industry, so basically Flyway is not an option for J2EE?

Comment: Well, that's not fully accurate. It integrates very well with Spring. You can see an example here which should suit your needs: http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/ApplicationIntegration . It will also detect the presence of Spring and allow Java migrations using JdbcTemplate if found.

Comment: @Subarule: I'm sorry, I meant that there is no extra support in Flyway for Spring, but the library can be easily integrated with it. See my update.

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. With all of these ideas can I say currently for Spring application we cannot avoid using queries(JdbcTemplte) doing the Flyway migration even the whole project is based on JPA? So the application need a Jdbc datasource for flyway?

Comment: @Subarule: even if you are using JPA, you still need a `DataSource`, which FlyWay requires to work. Also your database talks SQL, you can't avoid it.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz, That's right. Sorry to the confusion. My question is  JPA get its own rules to run sql at the background, but seems flyway needs explicitly queries to implement the migration?

Comment: @Subarule: JPA provider is clever enough to update the database schema (using SQL) based on JPA models changes. But when using FlyWay, you must use raw SQL queries, FlyWay knows nothing about JPA.

Comment: @Dreamer This is an interesting question. What did you finally end up using? I am using JPA to generate a schema file. Are you using something like hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update to generate schema diff for upgrade or writing custom scripts for schema updates?

Comment: @iamrohitbanga We finally choose liquibase instead of Flyway because requirement ask us to hand in a script upgrade scripts to clients each time so we expect something can generate such script diff. Also our application is not running on Hibernate. It seems like Liquibase is a little more powerful and better integration with Spring. But honestly both product doesn't give much of document to let people know the details about its integration with Spring.